# Protecting Entire Sheet using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a code in which it takes input for the ranges to protect from a particular cell and also the sheet ID from a different cell.
but now I want to protect the complete sheet and I don't want to add ranges to it
suggest me a change to my existing code through which I can protect the complete sheet

```
function protectRange() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Read values from specific cells
  var fileIds = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue().split(',');
  var rangeToProtect = sheet.getRange("B6").getValue();
  var editorsCell = sheet.getRange("B9");
  var editors = editorsCell.getValue();

  // Prepare the editors list
  var editorsArray = editors.split(',');
  for (var k = 0; k < editorsArray.length; k++) {
    editorsArray[k] = editorsArray[k].trim();
  }

  // Check if any required fields are empty
  if (fileIds.length === 0 || !rangeToProtect || editorsArray.length === 0) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Error", "Please fill up the Spreadsheet ID, Range, and List of Editors.", ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    return;
  }

  // Confirmation dialog box
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var confirmationMessage = "You are about to protect the range '" + rangeToProtect + "' and allow the following editors:\n\n" + editors;
  var response = ui.alert('Confirmation', confirmationMessage, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
    // Rest of the code to protect the range
    fileIds.forEach(function(fileId) {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId.trim());
      if (file.getMimeType() === MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId.trim());
        var sheets = ss.getSheets(); // Get all the sheets

        for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { // Iterate over all the sheets
          var currentSheet = sheets[i];

          // Skip if the sheet is hidden
          if(currentSheet.isSheetHidden()){
            continue;
          }

          // Clear existing protections on the range to protect
          var protections = currentSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
          for (var j = 0; j < protections.length; j++) {
            var protection = protections[j];
            if (protection.getRange().getA1Notation() === rangeToProtect) {
              protection.remove();
            }
          }

          // Create new protection on the specified range
          var range = currentSheet.getRange(rangeToProtect);
          var newProtection = range.protect();
          newProtection.setDescription('Range protection');

          // Add user emails to allow editing the protected range
          newProtection.addEditors(editorsArray);

          // Remove editors who are not in the list
          var currentEditors = newProtection.getEditors();
          for (var l = 0; l < currentEditors.length; l++) {
            var currentEditor = currentEditors[l].getEmail();
            if (editorsArray.indexOf(currentEditor) === -1 && currentEditor !== spreadsheet.getOwner().getEmail()) {
              // If the current editor is not in the editors list and not the owner
              newProtection.removeEditor(currentEditor); // Remove the editor
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    ui.alert('Range Protection', 'The range has been protected.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

this is the code and the second para holds the code to fetch data from the cell

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I would like to confirm about `protect the complete sheet`. Do you want to protect all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to protect a Google Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to protect one of the sheets in a Google Spreadsheet? Or others? And, I cannot understand the relationship between your goal and your showing script. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Like the code I have written is about protecting a common range in different spreadsheets like 
 // Read values from specific cells 
the code written under this header provides the address of the cells which provides the sheet ID, the range to be protected and the editors to be added 

but now I want to protect complete sheets like the spreadsheets have a single sheet in it and I want to protect it so that everything remains same in this code but I don't have to add the range to be protected but just something like protect("Entire Sheet")

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sheet.protect()` and `Sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0]`, like this:

```js
'use strict';

/**
* Protects all sheets in several spreadsheets the same way. Skips hidden sheets.
*/
function protectAllSheetsInManySpreadsheets() {
  const masterSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const masterSheet = masterSs.getActiveSheet();
  const _get = (rangesA1) => rangesA1.map(r => masterSheet.getRange(r).getDisplayValue().split(',').map(s => s.trim()).filter(String));
  const [fileIds, editors] = _get(['B3', 'B9']);
  if (!fileIds.length || !editors.length) {
    masterSs.toast('Please fill in spreadsheet IDs and list of editors.');
    return;
  }
  masterSs.toast(`Processing ${fileIds.length} spreadsheets...`, 'Please wait', -1);
  const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  const errors = [];
  let numAccessErrors = 0;
  let numProtected = 0;
  fileIds.forEach(fileId => {
    let ss;
    try {
      ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId).addEditors(editors.concat(me));
    } catch (error) {
      errors.push({ fileId: fileId, sheetId: null, sheetName: '(could not access spreadsheet)', });
      numAccessErrors += 1;
      return;
    }
    ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
      if (sheet.isSheetHidden()) return;
      if (protectSheet_(sheet, editors)) {
        numProtected += 1;
      } else {
        errors.push({ fileId: fileId, sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), sheetName: sheet.getName(), });
      }
    });
  });
  let msg = `Protected ${numProtected} sheets in ${fileIds.length - numAccessErrors} spreadsheets.`;
  if (numAccessErrors) msg += ` Could not access ${numAccessErrors} spreadsheets.`;
  if (errors.length) {
    msg += ` There were ${errors.length} errors: ${JSON.stringify(errors)}`;
    console.log(errors);
  }
  masterSs.toast(msg, 'Done', 30);
}


/**
* Protects a sheet, optionally leaving some ranges editable by all users.
*
* When warningOnly is truthy, editing a protected cell will show a warning to all users.
* When exceptRanges is empty, the sheet will be editable by editors and view-only to others.
* When exceptRanges is not empty, editors get edit access to the whole sheet, and others get edit access to exceptRanges.
* The account who runs the script is always included in editors.
* Removes existing range protections before protecting the sheet.
* Disables domain user default edit rights, if any.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {User[]} editors Optional. The users to grant edit access to the whole sheet.
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range[]} exceptRanges Optional. The ranges to leave unprotected and editable by others.
* @param {Boolean} warningOnly Optional. Determines whether to protect the range with 'show a warning' or 'restrict who can edit'.
* @return {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} The same sheet, for chaining, or null if the sheet could not be protected cleanly.
*/
function protectSheet_(sheet, editors = [], exceptRanges, warningOnly) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 27 February 2024
  try {
    const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    const sheetUnprotectOK = unprotectSheet_(sheet);
    const protection = sheet.protect().addEditor(me).setDescription('Protected by protectSheet_()');
    if (exceptRanges) protection.setUnprotectedRanges(exceptRanges);
    if (warningOnly) {
      protection.setWarningOnly(true);
    } else {
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors()); // remove editors inherited from spreadsheet
      protection.addEditors(editors.concat(me));
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    return sheetUnprotectOK ? sheet : null;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}


/**
* Removes all range protections in a sheet, and unprotects the sheet.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet The sheet to unprotect.
* @return {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} The same sheet, for chaining, or null if the sheet could not be fully unprotected.
*/
function unprotectSheet_(sheet) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 27 February 2024
  let sheetUnprotectOK = true;
  const rangeUnprotectOK = removeAllRangeProtections_(sheet);
  const protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (protection) {
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    } else {
      sheetUnprotectOK = false;
    }
  }
  return rangeUnprotectOK && sheetUnprotectOK ? sheet : null;
}


/**
* Removes all range protections in a sheet.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet The sheet where range protections are to be removed.
* @return {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} The same sheet, for chaining, or null if at least one range could not be unprotected.
*/
function removeAllRangeProtections_(sheet) {
  // version 1.3, written by --Hyde, 27 February 2024
  let rangeUnprotectOK = true;
  const protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  protections.forEach(protection => {
    if (protection.canEdit()) {
      protection.remove();
    } else {
      rangeUnprotectOK = false;
    }
  });
  return rangeUnprotectOK ? sheet : null;
}
```

I have not tried the above code so test it carefully. See [Sheet.protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect) and [Sheet.getProtections()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getProtections(ProtectionType)).