# Google Sheets script that automatically locks a sheet 24 hours after a cell is edited

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have been banging my head on this issue but I just can't seem to find a proper response to help me. Can anyone give me any clues how I could manage to do this? So I have an attendance form that has the employees, and then each day it's a different sheet. I would like after the day has ended, the employees wouldn't be able to access the past day's sheet anymore to edit their hours.

Is that even possible?

This is how a day's sheet looks like.

[image: This is how a day's sheet looks like.]

I have tried all kinds of scripts I've found on google but I haven't managed to reach a proper result. At most, I've managed to get a script that would protect a sheet upon activation (not when a cell is edited) and it would activate later with a separate timer script. But that seems way too complicated and I am sure there must a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run at the end of each day a function that protects that day's sheet. To automate that, add a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) and set it to fire at 23:00 hours.

The code to protect the current day's sheet could look like this:

```js
function protectTodaysSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetName = new Date().getDate();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  protectSheet_(sheet);
}
```

You can find my implementation of `protectSheet_()` (and its friends) at
[Protecting Entire Sheet using apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78068531/13045193).

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, judging by your code, I would need to manually input the different sheet name every day. It won't change automatically between them. I suppose I am back to my initial issue, cause I had an alternative that kinda worked but I didn't like that I would need to change the code every day. Is there no alternative for the sheets to be locked automatically?

Comment: The `new Date().getDate()` bit gets the current day number every day automatically.

Comment: Oh, okay. I asked because once I tried the code it gives me the error: "protectSheet_ is not defined". Would the title of the sheets conflict with the code that gets the date? Instead of "1","2" etc. should be changed to "DD.MM.YY" ?

Comment: _"protectSheet is not defined"_ — you need to include the `protectSheet_()` function and its friends in the script project. Follow the link I gave you. Refer to [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript) to learn the basics.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand. So there's more to it, I'll look it up. Thanks for helping me! Appreciate it.